# BASH copy all files except one

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, copy, cp

I would like to copy all files out of a dir except for one named Default.png. It seems that there are a number of ways to do this. What seems the most effective to you?

Comment: Why do you need it to skip that file, as opposed to just deleting it after copying it? Does it exist in the target directory already?

Comment: Yes a file with the same name is already living in the target dir.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Or you could want to save the time of copying it, if it's a large file. I'm interested in this but excluding a directory rather than a file.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Simple, if `src/` only contains files:

```
find src/ ! -name Default.png -exec cp -t dest/ {} +
```

If `src/` has sub-directories, this omits them, but does copy files inside of them:

```
find src/ -type f ! -name Default.png -exec cp -t dest/ {} +
```

If `src/` has sub-directories, this does not recurse into them:

```
find src/ -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -name Default.png -exec cp -t dest/ {} +
```

Comment: This turns out to be the best for me because it would appear that OS X ships without glob enabled.

Comment: @Max `\;` executes the command once per file. `+` runs the command once and passes all of the file names to it at once (subject to the command line length limit). `+` is a bit more efficient in general.

Answer (score 196):

Should be as follows:

```
cp -r !(Default.png) /dest
```

If copying to a folder nested in the current folder (called example in the case below) you need to omit that directory also:

```
cp -r !(Default.png|example) /example
```

Comment: This produces
-bash: !: event not found

Comment: Are you copying the files to a folder nested within the folder your copying from?

Comment: This requires `shopt -s extglob` to work, if it has been disabled.

Comment: It seems that OS X needs to use `shopt -s extglob` as described by @BarryKelly. With that, it works perfectly.

Comment: Years on Bash and didn't know about `!()`... Beautiful! For those that --like me-- feel it is time to study/review [bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html), here are the relevant links related to this question/answer: [shopt/extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) and [the pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching).

Comment: Just because I didn't quite grasp, at first, how to use this: `cp -r $src_path/!($file) $dest_path` would be equivalent to `cp $src_path/* $dest_path/ --exclude $file` if cp had such an argument.

Answer (score 100):

rsync has been my cp/scp replacement for a long time:

```
rsync -av from/ to/ --exclude=Default.png

-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
-v, --verbose               increase verbosity
```

Comment: If I want to exclude two different files, how do I use this?

Comment: multiple --exclude= arguments are supported.  And don't forget the `-r` arg if you're syncing directories

Comment: Note that it also copies hidden files (eg .git) and in case of same files overwrites them

Comment: this"rsync -aP --exclude=backup /root/jenkins_api/* /root/jenkins_api/backup" does not work when there is no files in /root/jenkins_api/**.Is there a workaround to skip when no files are found ?

Answer (score 4):

```
cp `ls | grep -v Default.png` destdir
```

Comment: This is more likely to produce errors than do what you intend.

Comment: ok @DennisWilliamson, can you explain why?

Comment: @arthur.sw For one thing, it doesn't account for files with spaces in it. As with many things with the shell, there's a bunch of edge cases that fail. 95%+ of the time, this stuff just works. Just need to be conscious of the caveats. Spaces in file names jump working with the shell from trivial to painful.

Comment: Another reason is that since there are no anchors in the regex and the dot isn't escaped it would also match a file named `myDefaultXpng.OLD` for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do:

```
cp srcdir/* destdir/ ; rm destdir/Default.png
```

unless the files are big. Otherwise use e.g.

```
find srcdir -type f/ |grep -v Default.png$ |xargs -ILIST cp LIST destdir/
```

Comment: The first command is not what the OP asked for. If `Default.png` exists in the two directories, it will replace the one in `destdir` by the one in `srcdir`, then delete the copied `Default.png`. Instead, the OP wants to keep the `Default.png` that already exists in `destdir`.

Comment: how about default.png already exists in destdir? Your solutioun won't work.

Answer (score 1):

### Jan, 2022 Update:

This is the easiest way(It's not complicated).

First, make **"temp" folder**:

```
mkdir temp
```

Second, copy all files from **your original folder** to **"temp" folder**:

***"-R" flag can copy exactly all files including "Symbolic Links"***

```
cp -R originalFolder/. temp/
```

Third, remove **"Default.png"** from **"temp" folder**:

```
rm temp/Default.png
```

Finally, copy all files from **"temp" folder** to **your destination folder**:

```
cp -R temp/. destinationFolder/
```

In addition, this is the shortest way without **"temp" folder**:

```
cp -R originalFolder/!(Default.png) destinationFolder/
```

Comment: At least I could understand it haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Below script worked for me

```
cp -r `ls -A | grep -v 'skip folder/file name'` destination
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# chattr +i /files_to_exclude
# cp source destination
# chattr -i /files_to_exclude
```

Answer (score -3):

use the shell's expansion parameter with regex

```
cp /<path>/[^not_to_copy_file]* .
```

Everything will be copied except for the not_to_copy_file

-- 
if something is wrong with this. please Specify !

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately your answer is not correct.  The bracket expresssion (`[...]`) contains a set of characters to match, while a leading `^` will cause a match of the complement of the listed characters.  In the following example, neither file will be listed: `touch not_to_copy_file to_copy_file ; ls [^not_to_copy_file]*` because all filenames starting with any of the following characters will be excluded: `_cefilnopty`.