# Bash copying files with variables

Tags: bash, copy, find, cron

New to bash scripting, I'm writing a script to copy my TV shows accross from a download folder to an archive folder.

So far I have this:

```
find `*`show1`*`.avi |  cp \"" $0 "\" "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show1" 
find `*`show2`*`.avi |  cp \"" $0 "\" "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show2"
```

I understand this is not the best method, but my skills of bash are quite limited.

I need to know how I can copy that found file, or do nothing if it doesnt find anything matching (this will be a cron script). 
eg.

```
find `*`show1`*`.avi |  cp "show1.hello.world.xvid.avi" "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show1" 
find `*`show2`*`.avi |  cp "show2.foo.bar.xvid.avi" "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show2" 
find `*`show3`*`.avi |  cp "null (nothing found)" "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show3"
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Solved http://pastebin.com/aNLihR86

Comment: A Kind of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313590/bash-copy-all-files-except-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name "*show1*" -exec cp {} /mnt/main/data/tv/Show1 \;
```

(Replace the . by the directory you want to look files into)

Comment: Thanks, however it returns: 
find /my/dir -name *show1* -exec cp {} "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show 1" \;
find: show1.pdtv.avi: unknown option

Comment: I think you have forgotten to quote the name param, it should be: find /my/dir -name "*show1*" -exec cp {} "/mnt/main/data/tv/Show 1" \;

Comment: When I quote it, it doesnt find anything (yes a file is there). find: No match

Comment: If you cp has -t option (--target-directory) you can improve efficiency with find . -name "*show1*" -exec cp -t /mnt/main/data/tv/Show1 {} +

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*show*
do
  case "$file" in
   *show1* ) dest="/mnt/main/data/tv/Show1" ;;
   *show2* ) dest="/mnt/main/data/tv/Show2" ;;
   *show3* ) dest="/mnt/main/data/tv/Show2";;
  esac
  cp "$file" "$dest"
done
```