# copy all files in folder, into a folder within that same path

Tags: linux, sh

In Linux shell, How can I copy all files from `/folder` into `/folder/sub`?

the normal way of copying recursively isn't working (which makes sense) because i'm copying a folder into itself...

Comment: oh, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313590/bash-copy-all-files-except-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cp -a !(sub) sub
```

You can exclude the sub directory.

From the comments on that [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313590/bash-copy-all-files-except-one):

If this doesn't work, you might need to enable:

```
shopt -s extglob
```