# Bash delete and copy multiple files with multiple extension

Tags: bash

I kind of got stuck in a situation. I wanted to copy certain files from one directory to another (non recursive).

I have multiple files with extensions like `.txt`, `.so`, `.so.mem`, `.so.lib`, `.lib` and multiple directories in a directory called `base`. I'd like to copy all the files non-recursively (only from the base directory) to another directory called `test`.

I did the following:

```
Try 1 
pushd $base
find -not -name '*.so' -not -name '*.so.*' -type f -print() -exec rm -f {} +
cp -f $base/* $test
```

In above try the find  has somehow deleted all except `.so`, even though I have written `-not -name '*.so.*'` i.e. files `.so.mem` and `.so.lib` should not be deleted.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: try it with `! -name '*.so'` instead of the not
to add: here is the url maybe it helps you
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313590/bash-copy-all-files-except-one)

Comment: Works for me: `touch a.txt a.so a.so.mem a.so.lib a.lib ; find -not -name '*.so' -not -name '*.so.*' -type f` only prints `a.lib` and `a.txt`. Next time, run without `-exec` first and check the output.

Comment: Never risk losing files; always run your code without risking damage before running the code with an active `-exec rm -f {} +`.  Put an `echo` in front of the `rm` if nothing else.  This is even more important if you're working with root privileges.  Exploring what an inaccurate `rm` will do if you're running as root is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, that's what you want:

```
mkdir test
# move all required files to the 'test' directory
mv base/*.txt base/*.so base/*.so.* base/*.lib test
# delete all remaining files from the 'base' directory
rm base/*
```

In the end, you'll have an empty `base` directory (assuming no hidden files) and a `test` directory full of `*.txt`, `*.so` and `*.lib` files.