# Bash: copy all files of a certain type excluding few

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting. The requirement is similar to [BASH copy all files except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313590/bash-copy-all-files-except-one). I'm trying to copy all files that starts with file and exclude one file that starts with file~ (backup file). This is what I hvae tried so far with bash.

```
path1="/home/dir1/file*" ( I know this * doesn't work - wildcards)
file_to_exclude="/home/dir1/file~*"
dest=/var/dest

count=`ls -l "$path1" 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $count !=0 ]
then
    cp -p !$file_to_exclude $path1 $dest (Not sure if this is the way to exclude backup file)
fi
```

Could anyone please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: how about `cp -p /home/dir1/file[^~]* $dest` ?

Answer (score 3):

use `find`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +0 ! -name *~* -exec cp {} dest \;
```

instead of line count this checks size being nonzero.

dest is the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
file_to_exclude="some_pattern"
all_files=`ls /home/dir1/file*`
for file in $all_files; do
    if [ "$file" != "$file_to_exclude" ]; then
        cp $file /some/path
    fi
done
```

Comment: yes. it is. do you have other suggestion how to get list of files?

Comment: `all_files=(*)`. Now you have a bash array and don't have to worry about whitespace issues until you expand each member.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason for complication, it could be as simple as:

```
cp -p /home/dir1/file[^~]* /var/dest/
```

Or, if you only want files with extensions

```
cp -p /home/dir1/file[^~]*.* /var/dest/
```