# Copy files with extension and exclude by filename

Tags: linux, bash, robocopy, cp

I'm trying to port the following robocopy command to Linux:

```
robocopy SrcDir DstDir *.dll *.pdb *.xml /xf Unity*.* nunit*.*
```

In other words, I want to:

- Include all `dll`, `pdb` and `xml` files
- *Unless* they start with `Unity` or `nunit`

I've read the following two threads, but can't figure the exact syntax:

- [Copy all files with a certain extension from all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories)
- [How to use 'cp' command to exclude a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585929/how-to-use-cp-command-to-exclude-a-specific-directory)

My best guess so far would be:

- Enable `shopt -s extglob`
- Go to the source directory `cd SrcDir`
- Use this command: `cp ((*.dll | *.pdb | *.xml) && !(Unity*.* | nunit*.*)) DstDir`

But I get syntax errors inside my conditional expression, starting at `*.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this command using `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob dotglob
cd "$srcDir"

cp !(@(Unity|nunit)).{dll,pdp,xml} "$dstDir"
```

Answer (score 0):

according to below link :

[BASH copy all files except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313590/bash-copy-all-files-except-one/1313688)

you can use below command :

```
find [YOUR_SOURCE_ADDRESS] \( -iname \*.dll -o -iname \*.pdb -o -iname \*.xml \) ! \(-name "Unity*" -o -name "nunit*" \) -exec cp -t [YOUR_DEST_ADDRESS] {} +
```

you can change [YOUR_SOURCE_ADDRESS] and [YOUR_DEST_ADDRESS] (with your serach address and destination address for copy)